# How to do automatic 2FA with SSH/SCP on Windows (ideally using PuTTY+WinSCP)?

Tags: windows-10, ssh, putty, winscp, two-factor-authentication

I am on Windows 10 using PuTTY and WinSCP to SSH/SCP into a linux server that has two-factor authentication (2FA). Each time I log in, it asks for my password and a verification code. I am curently using a chrome extension, "Authenticator", to get the one-time code, but other options are possible.  How can I automate PuTTY and WinSCP to automatically obtain and use the 2FA code, and ideally stay logged in all the time?

I do not have much control over the remote server --- although I could possibly ask for the sysadmins to make changes if necessary.

Comment: Are server and client both on Windows 10? Do the devices for skipping 2FA have always the same IP address?

Comment: @harrymc Good questions - I have edited the post to add this info. (Server is linux, client is Windows 10, current authentication device is iPhone. Server probably always has the same IP but the clients probably don't.)

Answer (score 2):

Neither WinSCP nor PuTTY provide a way to automate the 2FA authentication.

And even if they did, a question is whether the system that provides you the code (which you didn't tell us anything about) would allow you to obtain it automatically. It would kind of defy its purpose.

Comment: Currently I am using an authentication app like Authenticator on my phone to obtain the 2fa code. To set this up I scanned a QR code that I generated using the command `gen2fa new`.

Comment: I don't think it defies its purpose. Currently anyone in the world can access this server with just the password. I want my specific machines to be able to access the machine.

Comment: @rhombidodecahedron - If anyone can access the server with only the password then why did you indicate it’s asking for a 2FA code (likely based on time so it’s 6 digits?). You could likely write a bash and or PowerShell script that determines what the current code is if it’s based on time.

Comment: @Ramhound Sorry, I misspoke. Without 2fa any could access with just the password. I want my specific machines to be able to skirt the 2fa, which would clearly not defeat its purpose. And yes, it is asking for a 6 digit 2fa code with a timeout.

Comment: Your going to have to provide a valid TOTP code due to how the authentication system works. There are Python and PowerShell scripts that could be used to automate the process. What likely would work better is a hardware token.

Comment: @Ramhound thanks, could you please link me to such a script?

Comment: It depends on the Authenticator phone app that you want to use.

Comment: @JohnGreene Good point. I have an iPhone. Anything compatible would be fine by me!

Comment: @JohnGreene I have also just installed a chrome extension, Authenticator, that also helps here

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution is if your client IP addresses are static, which is
to set SSH on the Linux server to skip authorization for your IPs.

The post
[SSH Google Authenticator Ignore/Whitelist ips](https://serverfault.com/questions/799657/ssh-google-authenticator-ignore-whitelist-ips)
has this
[answer](https://serverfault.com/a/871384/18736):

> In "/etc/pam.d/sshd"
>
> ```
> auth [success=1 default=ignore] pam_access.so accessfile=/etc/security/access-local.conf
> auth required pam_google_authenticator.so
> ```
>
> Then on "/etc/security/access-local.conf"
>
> ```
> #localhost doesn't need two step verification
> + : ALL : 192.168.1.0/24
> + : ALL : LOCAL
> + : ALL : YOURIPHERE
> #All other hosts need two step verification
> - : ALL : ALL      Don't forget to restart ssh.
> ```

Beside IP addresses, I don't see another way of distinguishing
the clients. You might consider using a jump server having
a static IP, so that these clients will connect through it
and will this way be exempt from authentication.

Comment: What about using a Dynamic DNS and getting that IP to register per this method for dynamic public/Internet IP addresses. Would something of this nature be possible to integrate with this solution? Wonder what file line value needs changed for the specific IP address though too. I suppose it'd be somewhere in `/etc/security/access-local.conf`?

Comment: It's certainly possible, although not simple, to install Dynamic DNS on each of the client computers and have a cron script that modifies `access-local.conf` with their IP addresses. In my opinion an SSH jump server is the more secure option, since an ISP might reallocate the client's IP without notice.

Comment: Yea, you'd probably have to have it update the file with only the latest IPs, etc. and remove the old ones somehow. Sounds like it'd be complex indeed. Connecting to a VPN and then to the SSH server is another secure solution too.

Comment: That's an idea : set up a company VPN server and identify clients accessing via the VPN as exempt. It's equivalent in some ways to having an SSH jump server.

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not have much control over the remote server --- although I could possibly ask for the sysadmins to make changes if necessary.

Comment: My answer relates to the server. If you wish to try it, or my last comment, you will need the cooperation of the server's admin. Without it, you might just as well give up.

Comment: @harrymc "Without it, you might just as well give up." This surprises me. If I can get a valid authentication code through a chrome extension on windows, why isn't there a way to also get it and insert it automatically into putty/winscp?

Comment: Martin Prikryl said in the other answer that this is not supported. You better believe him, since he is the author of WinSCP... In my answer I'm trying to find a way for achieving it, but this requires server modifications.

Comment: @harrymc That is a valid point =D I still think there must be a way, even if it is not internal to WinSCP. I have been trying to use AutoHotKey to automate a series of copies and pastes and have gotten some parts down but so far I haven't come up with a very elegant solution.

Comment: AutoHotKey can do anything, but such a script will not be simple.